# How to enable mutual Authentication only if this is the option user chooses to authenticate the system?

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, mutual-authentication

We provide different type of authentication mechanisms for our users to authenticate our app.
One of them is using smart cards certificates installed on it. So I configured tomcat server.xml file (clientAuth = true) and added  client certificates  to my keystore file. When user hits the main page , list of user's authentication certificates pops up on the browser. When user selects one of them to authenticate, it redirects to the welcome page(login page) where we show list of authentication methods. But what I want to implement, when user hits the main page, still welcome page should be shown first. If user chooses authentication through certificates only in that case , we should enable mutual authentication and show user's certificates on browser. But if this is not the option chosen by user, we should not demand certificates from end-users and authenticate them with different options which they would choose. I can not use clientAuth=want , list of certificates still pops up, before the login page.

Currently  I am confused as i can not figure out how to accommodate different cases depending on the user preferences only with one tomcat server.xml file. Any guide/hint to realize it appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't do this just with configuration. You are going to need to write at least a custom Authenticator and possibly a custom Realm as well.

A configuration only solution should be possible if you use multiple instances of the web application. 1 that required CLIENT-CERT and the other that used the alternative. The downside is you have to deploy largely the same app twice, just with different authentication config.